# Monitor Tomcat server from java application

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, webserver, monitoring

I have a java web application that's running on a tomcat server and i want to monitor the memory usage of the server, the Active, expired and rejected `HTTP` petitions to the server, which petitions take longest to produce a response, etc.

Is this possible to do from java?? if so can anyone point me in the right direction? i've been trying to find documentation on how to acomplish this and havent found anything concrete.

ps: I don't want to use any external application to do it i want to be able to monitor the server from within my app.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for JMX.

Have a look at Tomcat's [monitoring page](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Monitoring) from the FAQ for more information.

Connecting using JMX and how to obtain various values is way more complicated than an appropriate answer on SO can cover, so please have a look at that. There's also a presentation I gave at ApacheCon 2015 about [monitoring Tomcat using JMX](http://home.apache.org/~schultz/ApacheCon%20NA%202015/Monitoring%20Apache%20Tomcat%20with%20JMX.pdf) which covers using an external tool for monitoring, but will give you some good information about how to find the data you are looking for (and even introduce some of your own data available for sampling from other tools).